# Logging JavaScript Calls in AWS SDK V3

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, express, logging

I am using **AWS SDK v2** in nodejs application where i use the **AWS.config.logger = console;** code to get the output of all AWS SDK call in the below format

[AWS s3 200 0.185s 0 retries] createMultipartUpload({ Bucket: 'js-sdk-test-bucket', Key: 'issues_1704' })

Here is the reference link for V2 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/logging-sdk-calls.html

I want to implement the same in **AWS SDK V3**

Comment: Some discussion on v3 migration and specifically loggers [here](https://serverless.pub/migrating-to-aws-sdk-v3/) and [here](https://kane.mx/posts/2023/aws-js-sdk-v3-verbose-logging/).